# (CopyLeft++) Non profit license - Extension to GNU

Tags: licensing, open-source-software

There are now many open source projects using licenses such as the [GNU General Public License](https://opensource.org/licenses/GPL-3.0).

Although releasing the source code for a project that has used this means that anyone can compile it into their own copy, meaning that trying to sell that compiled program would be silly. Could there or has there ever been a license created that specifically also prevents someone who copies, edits or distributes source code, blueprints or designs from making money in any form by using the concept/product under license.

For example, if such a license were applied to the Android SDK, Android application developers would not be able to charge people for products after using this software to create the application. Similarly, if a car included a part that was created under this license, the entire car could not be sold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are many. [Creative Commons Attribution Non-Commercial](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/4.0/) is an example.

Comment: Apart from CC0, [the Creative Commons licenses are not recommended for software](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#can-i-apply-a-creative-commons-license-to-software).

Comment: @Mark irrelevant - the OP asked if there are such licences - there are.

Answer (score 0):

If you create software from scratch, then you can use any license you want. if you create software based on some GPL licensed software, you have no right to put additional requirements on the user of the software. You may also be preventing that the software is combined with other open source software.

Comment: This doesn't relate to my question at al